Как убрать избыточные сообщения HRM и Webpack Dev Server в сборке Webpack?
В webpack, я использую webpack-dev-server и ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin для динамического обновления проекта в браузере при внесении изменений в код, но на каждое обновление в консоли возникают избыточные сообщения такого типа:

[webpack-dev-server] App updated. Recompiling... index.js:485
[webpack-dev-server] App hot update... log.js:39 [HMR] Checking for
updates on the server... log.js:39 [HMR] Updated modules: log.js:39
[HMR]  - ./src/components/App/App.tsx log.js:39 [HMR] App is up to
date.

Моя конфигурация webpack dev server:
import type { Configuration as DevServerConfiguration } from "webpack-dev-server";
import { BuildOptions } from "./types/types";

export function buildDevServer(options: BuildOptions): DevServerConfiguration {
   return {
      port: options.port ?? 3000,
      open: true,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
   };
}

